# Why isn't the Tkinter window showing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.11

I have a tkinter window that displays your cps on a text box and a clickable button. The cps is calculated with a 'while True:' loop but is somehow stopping the tkinter window from appearing. When the program is ran, no errors appear. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
c=0
cps1=0
cps2=0
cps=0
def click():
    global c
    c +=1
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(END, str(cps))
window = Tk()
text = Text(window, width=10, height=10)
buttonA = Button(window, text='Click Here!', command=click)
text.pack()
buttonA.pack()
while True:
    cps1 = c
    sleep(1)
    cps2 = c
    cps = (cps2-cps1)
```

Comment: You very rarely want to have a long lasting loop in a `tkinter` program, since it is expecting to manage all the events in something like: `window.mainloop()`. You *can* run functions regularly through the use of the `.after()` method.

Comment: I believe you need to call `window.mainloop()`.

Comment: Adding to what quamrana said, your loop doesn't do anything useful. It's just going to assign zero to `cps` for infinity, because that loop is the only thing that is going to run. None of the rest will ever be given a chance to do anything. This is your loop `5 sleep 5 5-5, 5 sleep 5 5-5, 5 sleep 5 5-5` for infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing a window because you forgot to add `window.mainloop()`.

In addition you should use [`.after`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/) instead of an infinite loop because nothing else will ever get executed. You can do something like that:

```
from tkinter import *
c=0
cps1=0
cps2=0
cps=0
def click():
    global c
    c +=1
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    text.insert(END, str(cps))
    
def update():
    global c, cps1, cps2, cps
    window.after(1000, update)
    cps2 = c
    cps = (cps2-cps1)
    cps1 = c

window = Tk()
text = Text(window, width=10, height=10)
buttonA = Button(window, text='Click Here!', command=click)
text.pack()
buttonA.pack()
update()
window.mainloop()
```

[***understanding mainloop***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Comment: `0.0` is not a correct index. For one, a text widget index should be a string rather than floating point number. For another, the first line starts at 1, not 0. The floating point number `0.0` works because the text widget is liberal in what it accepts, but using a floating point number promotes a poor coding habit that will eventually backfire. For example, `1.10` is not the same character as `"1.10"`.